# This file requires C++11 library support

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm trying to test a sample C++ application in Eclipse Indigo. I have created an executable project (so that the makefile is automatically generated). I use functions from , which means that I need library support for C++11. Now I know I have to specify somewhere -std=c++11, but I have no idea where to set that in project properties, and I would really like to avoid editing my own makefile. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the [docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features)?

Comment: Such settings are usually found in the `C/C++ Build` properties tree. It might be possible to set the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable there.

Comment: Nope, I didn't find that in the docs. And I can't find where in C/C++ build options are those environmental variables.

Comment: Which version of `g++` are you using? (You want GCC 4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following using Eclipse Kepler, the steps should be similar:

- open the project properties
- on the left side, open the `C/C++ Build` tree and click on `Settings`
- Now, on the right side should appear a settings pane that has a tab named `Tool Settings`. In that page, open the tree for the C++ compiler (eg. `GCC C++ Compiler`) and click on `Miscellaneous`.

You can now append `-std=c++11` to the string that is in the text field for `Other flags`.